# How to get key and value from selected options in Controller Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, select

I using Angularjs, and trying to get in controller, from view, selected options (key and value) in select.

How to get - key, I know, but how to get key and value?

**View:**

```
<select
    ng-change="Main.getLocalityByAddress(regions)"
    ng-model="regions"
    ng-options="data.id as data.name for data in Main.regions">

    <option value>{{"Select region" | localization:'index'}}</option>
</select>
```

**Controller:**

```
Main.getLocalityByAddress = function(selected_region) {
}
```

**Upd:**

Whats wrong?:

**Controller**

```
app.controller('Main', function($scope){
    var Main = {};

    $scope.getLocalityByAddress = function() {
        console.log($scope.regions); // undefined
    };

    $scope.Main = Main;
});
```

**View**

```
<select
    ng-change="getLocalityByAddress()"
    ng-model="regions"
    ng-options="data.name for data in Main.regions">
</select>
```

Comment: What is `Main.regions`?

Comment: There stored my regions, Main - Controller

Answer (score 4):

You can bind the entire object to model.

```
<select
    ng-change="changed()"
    ng-model="regions"
    ng-options="data.name for data in options">
</select>
```

And in the controller;

```
$scope.changed = function() {
    console.log($scope.regions);
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1462/)